# SQLite list ALL foreign keys in a database

Tags: sqlite

Is there a way of listing ALL foreign keys in a SQLite database?

They don't seem to be stored in sqlite_master and `PRAGMA foreign_key_list('table')` only lists one at a time.

Alternatively, is there a way of listing what foreign keys reference a table?

Comment: Not a clean solution, but a solution nonetheless for "is there a way of listing what foreign keys reference a table?" -> `sqlite3 test.sqlite .dump | less -j.99` and then search for "REFERENCES destTable".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With the SQLite shell, use the `.schema` instruction, and use GREP to filter lines containing `REFERENCES`.

From `shell.c` in the SQLite repository, today's version in the trunk, two queries:

```
SELECT sql
  FROM (
        SELECT sql sql, type type, tbl_name tbl_name, name name
          FROM sqlite_master
         UNION ALL
        SELECT sql, type, tbl_name, name
          FROM sqlite_temp_master
       )
 WHERE tbl_name LIKE shellstatic()
   AND type != 'meta'
   AND sql NOTNULL
 ORDER BY substr(type, 2, 1), name
```

and

```
SELECT sql
  FROM (
        SELECT sql sql, type type, tbl_name tbl_name, name name
          FROM sqlite_master
         UNION ALL
        SELECT sql, type, tbl_name, name
          FROM sqlite_temp_master
       )
 WHERE type != 'meta'
   AND sql NOTNULL
   AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_%'
 ORDER BY substr(type, 2, 1), name
```

The second one is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi thanks Benoit. I should have mentioned that I'll be doing this on an android client so won't have access the the SQLite shell. :(

Comment: Hi Benoit - this gives me the entire ddl for all tables, which is useful for sure but still leaves me with the problem of parsing out the foreign key specific stuff. It would probably be easier for me to call PRAGMA foreign_keys on the results of "SELECT tbl_name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'" but I'm trying to find an easier way of getting this?

Comment: @Fergal Moran: However this is still the best way I can think of.

Comment: @FergalMoran: the way you’re describing (get the table names from `sqlite_master`, then call `PRAGMA foreign_keys` for each of them) is the easiest way.  Unfortunately, PRAGMA results can’t be combined with SELECT statements...

Comment: @Benoit Thanks for your help, I will stick with the PRAGMA method for now as I think it will be easiest.

Comment: Thought I should complete by writing that the correct command to list a table's foreign keys is `PRAGMA foreign_key_list`, not `PRAGMA foreign_keys`.

Answer (score 31):

It seems that all (or many) of the `PRAGMA` commands can be *programatically selected* with a little trick;

Usually the are called like:

```sql
PRAGMA table_info('my_table');
PRAGMA foreign_key_list('my_table');
```

But this can also be done:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info('my_table');
SELECT * FROM pragma_foreign_key_list('my_table');
```

And the *schema* can also be (more or less) obtained:

```sql
.schema pragma_table_info
/* pragma_table_info(cid,name,type,"notnull",dflt_value,pk) */;

.schema pragma_foreign_key_list
/* pragma_foreign_key_list(id,seq,"table","from","to",on_update,on_delete,"match") */
```

So, to get all the fks a JOIN between `sqlite_master` and `pragma_foreign_key_list` can do the trick:

```sql
SELECT 
    m.name
    , p.*
FROM
    sqlite_master m
    JOIN pragma_foreign_key_list(m.name) p ON m.name != p."table"
WHERE m.type = 'table'
ORDER BY m.name
;
```

Just take care, that some fields of `pragma_foreign_key_list` like `table`, `from`, ... **must** be quoted;

#### 3rd party edit

The result of the query above for the sqlite sample database from [dbeaver](/questions/tagged/dbeaver)

[image: Dbeaver sqlite sample database er diagram]

looks like this

[image: Result of query for tables and their realtions]

Comment: Can't you omit `ON m.name != p."table"` since SQLite allows (INNER) JOIN without ON? (Treating it like ON 1=1, as in a CROSS JOIN.)

Comment: Afaik that is called Natural Join, where SQLite automatically tests for equality between the values of every column that exists in both tables. So I don't think that the `ON` can be omitted here. And as personal preference i prefer to type a few more characters and be explicit about what is happening.

Comment: Explicity is gold on many aspects but this ON instruction is making the request wrong regarding the op as it is excluding all the foreign keys that target their own table. You may want to remove it.